# How to render to the same page when an onchange event occurs in django ajax

Tags: django

How to render to the same html page when an onchange event (dropdown) occurs in django.

I'm able render to the same form when the event occurs but the html page is not refreshed.

**Question**

How do I get the get the page to render and refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a state change for a dropdown menu, i-e displaying its content (assuming you're talking about this) doesn't require to reload the page.

It's usually handled with javascript and you actually don't reload the page just to display the same one with just the opened menu.

To display dropdown menus, Bootstrap may interest you :

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/